# Am I supposed to exchange my 1949 international driving permit for a local driving license for a short stay in Vietnam?

Tags: international-travel, driving, driving-licenses, vietnam

Am I (French citizen with US and 1949 international driving licenses)  supposed to exchange my 1949 international driving permit for a local driving license for a short stay (1 to 3 weeks) to drive a car in Vietnam?

In the list of countries in international driving permits currently issued by American Automobile Association (AAA) in the United States (2019-10-14) it says I have to exchange my 1949 international driving permit for a local driving license:

[image]

However, on https://www.vietnam-immigration.org.vn/news/view/how-to-convert-driver-license-for-foreigner-living-in-vietnam-part-1.html ([mirror](http://archive.is/TUL2J))  it says that an international driving permit for a local driving license for foreigners who stay  in "Vietnam from 3 months and above":

> 1.1. Foreigners who reside, work or study in Vietnam or foreigners drive registered abroad that enter **Vietnam from 3 months and above**, with international or national driver license (issued abroad) are also valid for use, if they wish to drive registered abroad in Vietnam, **they have to apply for changing correlative Vietnamese driver license**.

Answer (score 2):

**No**, not unless your visa is for a duration longer than three months.

> To convert your current driving license or an International Driving Permit into a Vietnamese driving license, the applicant must first hold a valid Vietnam permit of at least three month's validity and a current driving license or a valid International Driving Permit.

[Vietnam Immigration](https://www.vietnam-immigration.org.vn/news/view/how-to-convert-driver-license-for-foreigner-living-in-vietnam-part-2.html)

Another source states this clearly

> g) Foreigners residing, working and studying in Vietnam for at least 03 months, having Diplomatic or Official Identity Card, Permanent Residence Card, Temporary Residence Card, stay permits and unexpired native driving licenses may apply for renewal with corresponding driving licenses of Vietnam if they wish to drive in Vietnam;

[Source](https://vanbanphapluat.co/circular-12-2017-tt-bgtvt-driving-tests-and-issuance-of-driving-licenses-for-road-motor-vehicles)

> enter Vietnam **from** 3 months and above

I believe that is a mistake in translation. **For** makes much more sense there